# Select de tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql, select

Como fazer um select de tabelas diferentes? Tipo, checar se há o valor em uma, se não, checar na outra.

Comment: poste a estrutura das suas tabelas e o que vc já tentou fazer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora a pergunta não deixe explicito o contexto, vou tentar responder da forma mais genérica possível (embora para mim seja quase impossível não pensar no PostgreSQL. :-))

Digamos que temos o seguinte esquema

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    code char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    code char(5) CONSTRAINT secondkey PRIMARY KEY);
```

E as seguintes inserções:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('3');

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('4');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('5');
```

Digamos que precisamos recuperar o code='5', mas não sabemos em que tabala está, então um caminho seria:

```
SELECT code FROM Table2 WHERE code='5' and code NOT IN 
    (SELECT code FROM Table1 where code='5')
```

Se eu entendi corretamente a questão, esse é um caminho.

Comment: Embreando que para cada linha da tabela code o DB vai executar o subselect (SELECT code FROM Table1 where code='5')